# calling Thread.sleep() from synchronized context in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, thread-sleep

I have read that `Thread.sleep()` will pause the currently running thread for the time specified after which it goes back to runnable state waiting for it's turn to run.

Also, if called from `synchronized` context, `sleep()` doesn't release the lock it holds. So I was wondering when it will release the lock. If the thread, put on sleep, never gets the chance to run so it will always keep the lock with itself and then how other threads get to enter synchronized methods/block.

I am not sure if I am asking valid question. But please help me out.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> So I was wondering when it will release the lock.

It will release the lock upon exit from the `synchronized` block, and not earlier.

> If the thread, put on sleep, never gets the chance to run so it will always keep the lock with itself and then how other threads get to enter synchronized methods/block.

Quite simply, other threads will not be able to enter code that's synchronized *on the same object* that the sleeping thread.

To summarize, calling `Thread.sleep()` from a `synchronized` block is likely not a good idea.

Comment: Really, calling `Thread.sleep()` is likely not a good idea at all. If there's something you can do now, you should do it now. If you have to wait for something before there's anything you can do, you should wait for that something rather than sleeping.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I agree. While there are legitimate uses for `Thread.sleep()`, it is often used where it shouldn't be.

Comment: Well explained, but saying "To summarize, calling Thread.sleep() from a synchronized block is likely not a good idea." is going too far. Sometimes you want to wait and keep the lock.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, what do you mean with "you should wait for that something rather than sleeping"?

Comment: @UtenteStack If you're waiting for the phone to ring, you should wait for the phone to ring. You shouldn't go to sleep for 4 seconds and then check if the phone rang while you were asleep. If there's something you're waiting for, you should wait for that something rather than sleeping.

Comment: I'll make you an example: I have to sample tweets using TwitterStream. This API has a limit on the number of calls per 15 minutes. So that, I'm forced to use Thread.sleep() from a call to another...how should I do otherwise?

Comment: The code that permits the calls to the API should use a timer to trigger a call to `notify`. The code that makes the API calls should be waiting for permission using `wait`. Even if you combine these two functions into one piece of code, the operation will be triggered by the timer, so there's no need to call `sleep`. Rather than have a thread wait for something to happen so that it can do work, have the thing happening cause the work to be done so nothing needs to wait.

Answer (score 20):

If you use `Object.wait` instead of `Thread.sleep`, the lock from the synchronized block will be released.